# Input shape error in Tensorflow/Keras Conv2D layer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a convolutional neural network with Keras for the first time, and I just ran into some issues. The purpose of the CNN is to detect patterns in 490x640px grayscale images, which I have converted into 3D numpy arrays. Every image from the image data column of my Pandas dataframe has the shape `(490, 640, 1)`.

My code looks like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Assigning values to split the dataset into training and test data.
X = data[0]
Y = data[1]

# Allocate 20% of the dataset to be used as test data
train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

class_names = ['Neutral', 'Anger', 'Contempt', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Sadness', 'Surprise']

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(490, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(490, 640, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(100, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

My model's summary at this point looks like this:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 488, 638, 490)     4900      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 244, 319, 490)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 242, 317, 100)     441100    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 121, 158, 100)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 119, 156, 100)     90100     
=================================================================
Total params: 536,100
Trainable params: 536,100
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I then have the following:

```
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

The problem is that when I try to run this, I get the following error:

**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (261, 1)**

I must point out that `train_images.shape` returns the value `(261,)`, whereas `train_images[0].shape` returns `(490, 640, 1)`.

It makes sense to me in theory, but I'm still lost on how to properly shape my data for my CNN, and also detect if I'm doing anything else wrong.

Comment: What type is your input data? (with `type(train_images)`).
Also, do you get an error when you convert your data into a numpy array with: `numpy.array(train_images)`?

Comment: What is returned if you first convert X and Y to numpy arrays and then print `train_images.shape`?

Comment: @Nakor When I run `type(train_images)`, I get `pandas.core.series.Series`. I tried converting it to a numpy array but I'm still getting the same ValueError message.

Comment: @RichardX When I try that, I get `(261,)`

Comment: Ok, and what is the output of `numpy.array(train_images.values).shape`? Can you also show what you get when you do `train_images.head()`?

Comment: @Nakor When I run `np.array(train_images.values).shape` after using the `train_test_split()` function from `sklearn.model_selection`, I get the following: `(261,)`
As for `train_images.head()`, it returns what looks like rows of 3D numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your images are not of equal sizes. You can verify that easily, e.g.:

```
shapes = list()
for i in X:
    shapes.append(i.shape)

sorted_shapes = np.sort(np.array(shapes).sum(axis=1))
assert sorted_shapes[0] == sorted_shapes[1], 'Not all pictures have equal size.'
```

If this line throws an error, you'll have to crop/resize them.

Comment: That's true, but even then, the first 10 images from my dataset are all of the same size (490x640). When I restrict my training set and test set to these, I don't get any error with your code. But I still can't fit my model because I get this error: `Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 1)`